# Checking user role in pages

Tags: php, oop, laravel, design-patterns

I have parent `User` class whose instance is returned when the user is authenticated. That `User` instance has `role_id` which indicates the user's role. There are three roles in the system; standarduser, trainer and gym (each has different table in database) and each has different functions and privileges.

There are some possibilities I can do;

1) I can write role checks in `User`'s model class;

```
public function getName()
{
    if($user->role == 0)
    {
        $user->standarduser()->name;
    }
    else if($user->role == 1)
    {
        $user->gym()->name;
    }
}

public function getGymUsers()
{
    if($user->role == 2)
    {
        $user->gym()->users;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) I can write functions to each role class but in view (or controller), I have to do that control;

```
if($user->isStandarduser())
{
    echo $user->standarduser()->name;
}
. . .

if($user->isGym())
{
    echo $user->gym()->users;
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
```

3) Making specific views for each model so there will be no need to check roles. For example, if I'm in gym's page, I don't check if the object is a gym object because I know it's the gym's page.

I can't decide which way to go. If there are some better designs I can also try them.

Comment: Where are stored the method gym(), standartUser() and other. They are function or attribute ?

Comment: I would go with number 3. A gym's page would be very different from a standard user's page, I imagine. You can break the views into sections, and include sections that are similar for all users

Comment: @Sakuto gym() is Laravel's relation function. It automatically relates with foreign key and get the data.

Comment: @andrewtweber Gym and trainer have some additional divs and buttons. Apart from that I have to duplicate more pages if I go with that way. Is it seem better than other options?

Comment: @Cem see Tyler's answer. You can reuse parts of the views and just need extra files for the parts that are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gym and the user's view are extremely similar and you are using the blade engine provided by laravel then you can use blade's template system

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

**/resources/layouts/default.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <h1>@yield('name')</h1>
    <div>@yield('content')</div>
    <p>stuff that is the same for all users</p>
</body>
```

**/resources/gym.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('name',$user->gym()->name)

@section('content')
<p>This is content unique to the gym</p>
@endsection
```

**/resources/standarduser.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('name',$user->standarduser()->name)

@section('content')
<p>This is content unique to a standard user</p>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id){
    $user = User::where($id)->first();
    if($user->isGym())
        return view('gym', ['user' => $user]);
    else if($user->isStandardUser())
        return view('standarduser', ['user' => $user]);
    else
        abort(500,'Not implemented yet');
}
```

Because each view is extending the default layout you will be able to have shared components while providing unique components for each type of user